# Why don't I see a mix of threads executing the for loop

Tags: c, openmp

I have set the number of threads to 4.

My problem is I see a sequential type behavior in the following code. I would like to see all threads print their id in random ways, which is how a pthread implementation would behave.

```
#include <omp.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define CHUNKSIZE 5
#define N 1000

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
   int nthreads, tid, i, chunk;
   float a[N], b[N], c[N];

   /* Some initializations */
   for (i=0; i < N; i++)
     a[i] = b[i] = i * 1.0;
   chunk = CHUNKSIZE;

   #pragma omp parallel for schedule(static,10) shared(a,b,c) private(i,tid)
   for (i=0; i<N; i++)
   {
      tid = omp_get_thread_num();
      c[i] = a[i] + b[i];
      printf("Thread %d: c[%d]= %f\n",tid,i,c[i]);
   }
}
```

Output from a section:

```
Thread 2: c[949]= 1898.000000
Thread 2: c[980]= 1960.000000
Thread 2: c[981]= 1962.000000
Thread 2: c[982]= 1964.000000
Thread 2: c[983]= 1966.000000
Thread 2: c[984]= 1968.000000
Thread 2: c[985]= 1970.000000
Thread 2: c[986]= 1972.000000
Thread 2: c[987]= 1974.000000
Thread 2: c[988]= 1976.000000
Thread 2: c[989]= 1978.000000
Thread 0: c[1]= 2.000000
Thread 0: c[2]= 4.000000
Thread 0: c[3]= 6.000000
Thread 0: c[4]= 8.000000
Thread 0: c[5]= 10.000000
Thread 0: c[6]= 12.000000
Thread 0: c[7]= 14.000000
Thread 0: c[8]= 16.000000
Thread 0: c[9]= 18.000000
Thread 0: c[40]= 80.000000
Thread 0: c[41]= 82.000000
Thread 0: c[42]= 84.000000
Thread 0: c[43]= 86.000000
Thread 0: c[44]= 88.000000
Thread 0: c[45]= 90.000000
Thread 0: c[46]= 92.000000
Thread 0: c[47]= 94.000000
Thread 0: c[48]= 96.000000
Thread 0: c[49]= 98.000000
Thread 0: c[80]= 160.000000
Thread 0: c[81]= 162.000000
Thread 0: c[82]= 164.000000
Thread 0: c[83]= 166.000000
Thread 0: c[84]= 168.000000
Thread 0: c[85]= 170.000000
Thread 0: c[86]= 172.000000
Thread 0: c[87]= 174.000000
Thread 0: c[88]= 176.000000
Thread 0: c[89]= 178.000000
Thread 0: c[120]= 240.000000
Thread 0: c[121]= 242.000000
Thread 0: c[122]= 244.000000
Thread 0: c[123]= 246.000000
```

Comment: It's *is* being interleaved. But not at the granularity that you expect. On my machine, there's about 100 lines before a different thread appears.

Answer (score 0):

Is your machine single-core? If so, threads are probably spawned sequentially, and your OS uses round-robin scheduling to execute each thread. You'll only see interleaved threads on multi-core machines.

EDIT:

In line with my comment below, I think what you want to see is randomness in which thread executes, which is not the case depending on your OS scheduler.

It's not really useful to do multithreading on a single core machine. Parallelism to two threads might give you a small performance boost, but you'll have diminishing returns, and overhead of forks and joins will quickly make performance drop.

Comment: if it is spawned sequentially, i see no benefit in using openmp on a single core. Pthreads would be better because it can execute threads in interleaved manner.

Comment: Yes, pthreads can spawn threads in an interleaved manner, but that does not mean they'll execute randomly. This is more of an OS issue, as each thread only gets a discrete time slot for the CPU when it begins executing. If each thread completes within this time slot, you'll see all threads finish their work sequentially. Otherwise you'll just see them work round-robin style (assuming this is how your OS does scheduling).